# Add word 'Chapter' before chapter number in toc (memoir class)

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, chapters

i want to have the word 'ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ' which means Chapter in greek, before the chapter number in the table of contents and the 'ΠΑΡΑΡΤΗΜΑ' before appendices, i am using memoir class and the command \tableofcontents* for the produstion of toc. 
I provide a MWE, and a picture of what i get now. The number 1 before the chapter title, is inserted automatically in the toc.

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\makeatletter %
\makechapterstyle{sofia}{
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-48pt}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{5\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
  \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\raggedright\bfseries\huge\SingleSpacing}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont \@chapapp}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{\space}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\bfseries\huge}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{\vspace*{\midchapskip}\vspace*{5mm}}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\raggedright\bfseries\HUGE}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont ##1}
  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{sofia}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*{}
\clearpage
\cleartorecto
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\cleartorecto
\listoftables
\clearpage
\input{ch01}
\input{ch02}
\input{app1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See if `\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ \thechapter}` does the trick?

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ~}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{7em}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just `\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}` in order to get at prefix into the toc

Just as an addition to the comment, if you want to do the same with the appendices in the toc, use

```
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendicname~}
```

Comment: thanx a lot, what if i want the same for the appendix with the word 'Παράρτημα' instead of 'ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ'? what is the variable?

Comment: Guess, hint it is in the name of the variable.