# Put some text before \chapter{} in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I mean like having the table of content like:

Chapter X. Introduction

Chapter X. Abstract

Chapter X. Greetings

Where "X" is the automatic number put by LaTex.

All I've achieved is the following output, but I added "Capítulo 1." manually

[image: Issue]

Here's all packages I'm importing to my project, and my `\documentclass`

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm,right=25mm,left=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
```

I'm importing `.tex` files by `\import{pathtofile}{filename}` as following

```
\import{part_1_introduction/}{introduction.tex}
\import{part_1_introduction/}{issue_statement.tex}
\import{part_1_introduction/}{justification.tex}
\import{part_1_introduction/}{general_objective.tex}
```

Where each file contains following commands at the very beginning of it

```
\part{Parte II. Estado del arte}
```

or

```
\chapter{Marco conceptual}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This should be quite easy to do, but it's very specific to the document class you are using and the packages you load. Can you please elaborate a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document that contains the `\documentclass` command and all the `\usepackage`s you do?

Comment: Do you want `1. Capítulo 1. Introducción` (which is a bit redundant, in my opinion) or `Capítulo 1. Introducción` (without the first `1.`). Or something else?

Comment: I want the second one `Capítulo 1. Introducción`, because the first one is redundant

Comment: Similar: [Add word 'Chapter' before chapter number in ToC (`memoir` class)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227788/5764)

Comment: Related: [Writing Chapter Prefix for Chapter entries in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176212/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch the `\chapter` macro to write `Capítulo~` before the chapter number. Just add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter
             {\numberline {\thechapter }}
  {\@chapapp~ \numberline {\thechapter }}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother
```

The code above uses the `\patchcmd` command from `etoolbox`. `\patchcmd` takes four arguments:

```
\patchcmd{<command>}{<find>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<fail>}
```

it searches for the first occurrence of `<find>` the definition of `<command>` and, if found, replaces by `<replace>` and executes the `<success>` code. Otherwise executes the `<fail>` code.

I applied the patch above to the `\@chapter` macro which, in the `book` class, contains

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
```

which writes a line in the `.toc` file adding the current chapter to the table of contents.

The patch searches for `\numberline{\thechapter}` (which whites the chapter number) and inserts `\@chapapp~` before it. `\@chapapp` is the word `Capítulo` when you are writing in spanish, but is something else in other language, and `~` is a space.

The `<success>` code is empty because we don't want `\patchcmd` to execute anything else. The fail code, on the other hand, contains `\FAIL` (which isn't defined) so that if, for any reason, the patch fails, `\patchcmd` warns you, instead of silently ignoring the failed patch.

> [image]

Compilable example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm,right=25mm,left=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
% \addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter
  {\numberline {\thechapter }}
  {\@chapapp~ \numberline {\thechapter }}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% Dummy text for the example
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted. But I want to understand the code, can you explan it?

Comment: @BryanArreola I added an explanation. I hope it's clear enough. If it isn't, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion using package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\chaptername},% adds the prefix
  dynnumwidth% calculates the needed numberwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\entryprefix[2]{#1~#2~}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\chapter{Chapter title with many words, so it is longer than one line and needs a second line}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Note that the second line of an entry is aligned with the text of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tocloft` package:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Capitulo }
```

will put Capitulo and a space before the chapter number in the ToC.