# How to add Word CHAPTER # for each chapter name in toc (for .sty file)

Tags: table-of-contents, packages

How to add Word CHAPTER # for each chapter name in toc (for .sty file)

This code from .sty file

```
  \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{{
    \setlength{\topmargin}{2in}   % really 1.5in, added by bph
                                    % to meet OAP standards
    \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries  %the size of the font of the headers   of the chapter
    \begin{center}
    \etchapterheadstyle{\@chapapp{ \thechapter}}  %  CHAPTER 1 or APPENDIX


    \etchapterheadstyle{#1}                       %     TITLE OF CHAPTER
    \end{center}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{1.5in}   % back to 1in

}}
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{{ 

    \setlength{\topmargin}{2in}   % really 1.5in, added by bph
                                    % to meet OAP standards
    \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries   
    \begin{center}
    \etchapterheadstyle{#1}                       %     TITLE OF CHAPTER
    \end{center}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{2in}   % back to 1in
}}
```

The TOC shown as follow

[image: TOC]

How to appear TOC as:

CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION

CHAPTER 2 Chapter 2 name

CHAPTER 3 Chapter 3 name

After I add the below code from Peter Wilson
this toc appears
[image: New TOC after adding below code from Peter Wilson]
The Question is
1- How can I remove the word CHAPTER at the beginning of chapters toc
2- How can I make the title font smaller
3- list of figure - tables - symbols appear at the same page how can I make each of them in a single page?

Comment: See [Put some text before `\chapter` in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450786/5764)

Comment: @Werner Duplicate?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I'd think so. Was hoping someone could identify a higher-scoring duplicate, since this has been asked before. Similar to [List of Figures - how to add caption label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12865/5764).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Adding word "Chapter" into Table of Contents for only numbered chapter entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171047/5764); [Add "chapter" word into ToC using `tocbibind` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278804/5764)

Comment: @Werner I voted to close applying one of your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
...
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER } % CHAPTER before number in ToC
\newlength{\mylen} % a scratch length
\settowidth{\mylen}{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum} % extra space
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\mylen} % add the extra space
...
```

Adding something before the chapter/section number means you have to allow extra spacing for the additional text. That is what the last three lines of the above code does. Of course you could just set `\cftchapnumwidth` to your specified value without the fiddle of the above code.

See the documentation (`> texdoc tocloft`) for more information.

Comment: When I add the above code the word CHAPTER appears before each chapter name but the font change and the list of tables list of figures appears at the same page of toc page, (before adding this code each of them appear in a single page). Moreover, the word CHAPTER appears at the beginning of chapters toc . How can I delete it??

Comment: Please see the figure added to the post above

Comment: @ahmadHani I have no idea what you have done as you have not provided a MWE (from `\documentclass... ` to `\end{document}`) The code I provided puts CHAPTER before the chapter numbers in the ToC and with my test document changes nothing else. I can't help any more.