# Adding the word "Chapter" to the chapter in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I want to add the word "Chapter" before the chapter number in the TOC (keeping the code) as follows

`Table of contents`

`Chapter 1: Chapter name`

and no as

`Table of contents`

`1 Chapter name`

How do it please?

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\contentsmargin{0cm}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}}
{\color{ocre}}
{\ \color{ocre!60}\normalsize\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}
[2.5cm] 
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
{}
{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[3.75cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
{} 
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

 \subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this may be helpful for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477325/how-to-add-word-chapter-for-each-chapter-name-in-toc-for-sty-file

Comment: No its not my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\titlecontents{chapter}
[3.5cm] 
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries } 
{ \color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large Chapter\enspace\thecontentslabel]{3.6cm}\color{ocre}}
{\color{ocre}}
{\ \color{ocre!60}\normalsize\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
```

[image: a]

Comment: It's done, many thanks to @Simon Dispa.

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the `titletoc` package but instead the `tocloft` package. The following code provides what you ask for.

```
% chapintocprob.tex  SE 623588

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter } % put this before chapter number
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{4em} % extra space for the above
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:} % put : after chapter number
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % use detted leader
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\color{ocre}} % ocre colour for title and dots
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries\color{ocre}} % ocre page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\baselineskip}} % extra space below chapter titles

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries} % bold section titles
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % bold section leader
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries} % bold section page number

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % PW suggested by package french.ldf

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\begin{comment}

\contentsmargin{0cm}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}}
{\color{ocre}}
{\ \color{ocre!60}\normalsize\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}
[2.5cm] 
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
{}
{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[3.75cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
{} 
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\end{comment}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

 \subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

`tocloft` provides controls for all aspects of the ToC (and LoF, LoT) typesetting, from before the division number, through the dotted line to the page number and afterwards. It might be tedious to use but then it gives you conplete control over the typesetting of the ToC, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much @Peter Wilson